# Tire and rim sizing, tubeless conversion?

Tags: tire, rims

I am looking to shave some weight off my wheels. I am currently commuting on a 26" MTB.

The ETRTO size of the rim is 559x22 and the tires are 559x54. As my commute is through the city center, I want to change to slick tires.

The question here is will the 559x42 slick tires fit on the rim?

Also, can I go tubeless with "Stan's NOTUBES" conversion kit?

Answer (score 1):

Can't speak to the tubeless conversion kit, but pretty much any 559xwhatever tire should fit those rims. A given rim width can accommodate a wide range of tire widths. Seeing as how your desired tires are only 2 mm different, you'll definitely be OK.

Answer (score 1):

Tyres come narrower than 559x42 - you can get 26x1.1 Schwalbe Durano that inflate to 110 psi. With less material than a 559x42 tyre they will be lighter and run at higher pressure.

Continental Gatorskins come in 26 x 1 1/8" and are popular with shops and riders.

Both of these tyres will fit on your rims with no problems (as will 42). As for the narrower width, plenty of road bikes win races and deal with city streets on less.

I run narrow Panaracer T-Serv's on one bike and bigger Schwalbe Marathons on another bike. On balance I think that over-doing the thinness results in too harsh a ride with no real difference in weight/acceleration, so maybe your plan to use Stan's NOTUBES might be either a) more hassle than it is worth or b) the only way to get comfort and light weight. You will need a bullet-proof tyre though...

I am not sure I would want a puncture with 'glued on' tyres, but that is not what you are asking. Ask at your LBS in the workshop for 'from the horses mouth' on the current deal on tubeless. Also check your rims make and model with 'Stan's' site.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, once I had very wide DH rim on my MTB city bike (that was tempo fix, I had no other rims to put on). On that rim I had 1" slick, and the rim was slightly wider that the actual tire. 
So you should have no problems with any width of a tyre on your rims.

Comment: But, of course, it would be unwise to attempt to put a tubeless on a rim wider than the tire.  (I say "attempt" since you'd probably never even get it to seal.)

Comment: To be honest, I've never seen slick thin tires to be tubeless..

Comment: I was just attempting to answer (in this context) the OP's second question.